# Azure Function Sengrid - Attachment only working locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I'm trying to add a file to a mail sent by an azure function.

Here my function :

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "SendGrid"
#r "System.Web"

using System.Web;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log, out SendGridMessage message)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
    EmailContent data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailContent>(requestBody);

    if (data == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Data could not be null");
    }

    message = new SendGridMessage();

    message.AddTo(data.Email);
    message.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("no-reply@netflio.com"));
    message.AddContent("text/html", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(data.Body));
    message.AddAttachment(data.AttachmentName, Convert.ToBase64String(data.Attachment));
    message.SetSubject(data.Subject);

    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult("OK");
}

public class EmailContent
{

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }

}
```

My function works very well in my local machine but not on my azure function.

The file is missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it and it works well both in locally and on azure. You could refer to the steps as below:

1.Create a HttpTrigger on portal and configure Outputs.

[image]
2.Add sendgrid function in HttpTrigger. As you have set up the Outputs, ToAddress, FromAddress, MessageText and MessageSubject all have contain.

[image]

3.The output.

[image]